# Android intent to select audio OR record audio

Tags: android, audio, android-intent, voice-recording

I am using the following code to launch an intent to ***select audio***:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("audio/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(
        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Audio"), SELECT_AUDIO
);
```

Alternatively, if I replace the above code with the below, I can launch an intent to ***record audio***:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION); 
startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_AUDIO);
```

However, this does not give the option to either **select audio** *OR* to **record audio** using a voice recorder application. How can I give the user this choice?

Comment: Have u got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("audio/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

Intent intent2 = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);

Intent chooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, intent);
chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "title");
Intent[] intentarray= {intent2};
chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,intentarray);
startActivity(chooser);
```

I don't test it. If it doesn't work, please comment error message.